# How do I mix multiple live voice audio stream from DatagramPackets?

Tags: java, android, udp

I am working on a project where I like to add a *push-to-talk* functionality and
I have `android` as clients and `java` as my server. What I do is send `bytes` from `AudioRecord` to my server and broadcast it back to connected clients.

What my problem lies when mixing `data` from different clients that were sent at the same time.

This is what I have tried on my server:

```
static boolean status = true;
static int port = 1938;
static byte[] mixed_audio;
static byte[][] all_bytes;
static int client_count = 0;
static DatagramSocket socket;
static ArrayList<InetAddress> addresses;
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);    
    System.out.println("Listening. . .");    
    addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int x = 0; x < args.length; x++){
        if(args[x].equals("-p")){
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[x+1]);
        }
    }

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1400];

    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
            receiveData.length);

    socket = new DatagramSocket();

    while (status == true) {
        all_bytes = new byte[1400][1400];
        mixed_audio = new byte[1400];
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);        
        int a = addresses.indexOf(receivePacket.getAddress());
        if(a < 0 ){
            addresses.add(receivePacket.getAddress());            
        }
        client_count++;        
        all_bytes[client_count] = receivePacket.getData();
       new Thread(new ReceiveData(receivePacket.getData(), receivePacket.getAddress())).start();

    }
}

public static class ReceiveData implements Runnable{

    byte[] data;
    InetAddress address;

    public ReceiveData(byte[]  b, InetAddress address){
        this.data = b;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < 1400; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 1400; j++){
                    mixed_audio[j] += all_bytes[i][j];
                }
            } 

            if(client_count > 1){
                int c=0;
                for(int x = 0; x < 1400; x++){
                    mixed_audio[x]  = (byte) (mixed_audio[x] / client_count + 1);
                }
            }else{
                mixed_audio = data;
            }
            client_count--;

            for(InetAddress add: addresses){

                if(add != address){
                    DatagramPacket packet;
                    packet = new DatagramPacket(mixed_audio, mixed_audio.length, add, port);
                    socket.send(packet);

                }

            }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(TeraMix.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

The audio output when only one client is talking is clear but the audio output when multiple clients start to talk simultaneously becomes very unclear.

I also tried my algorithm for mixing audio by using it on files on my PC and it worked good. What I need is to mix `data packets` that are sent at the same time by different clients.

Do I need to handle clients on different threads? Am I doing it wrong?
is there a better way on this?
please guide me on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've been able to debug how the packets are merging there, but from a read through I would say the problem is that each received packet spawns it's own thread, which will then send the current merged packet.

E.g. if it's three clients A, B and C, sending in packets 1 and 2, the merges would be:

- A1 in -> A1 out
- B1 in -> B1, or maybe A1+B1 out
- C1 in -> C1, or B1+C1 or even A1+B1+C1 out
- A2 in -> A2 or C1+A2 or ...
- B2 in -> B2 or A2+B2 or ...
- C2 in -> C2 or B2+C2 or ...

It looks in this simplified case, it would have sent out six packets instead of the ideal two - A1+B1+C1 and A2+B2+B2?

Clearly this will take a bit of care to get the merge smooth, especially as I'm sure the packets won't be arriving perfectly in sync - this is UDP after all.

Assuming it's OK to work on a 'merge what packets you have' basis, it might work to only trigger the send thread when either you have packets for all current clients now, or if a second packet arrives for one of the clients, or maybe after a timeout on the sample rate.

I guess this would risk contention over `all_bytes` between the receiving and sending threads though.  It might work better to pass the current `all_bytes` through to the `ReceiveData` runnable once enough packets are in, but then start a new one to read more packets into.  Or at least cycle the arrays if memory/GC overhead could be an issue.